# Launch Camera App in Xamarin forms without taking picture or any action

Tags: xamarin.forms, launcher

One of the requirements i have is to scan a barcode which is a built in feature in most modern phones. Thus, i just need to launch the camera app.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: if you expect your app to be able to use the scanned barcode data, there is no way to do that from the camera app

Comment: Use [ZXing](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) or [Jimmy Puns Barcode Scanner](https://github.com/JimmyPun610/BarcodeScanner.Mobile)

Comment: @Jason, I understand that, i just want to launch the camera

Comment: @Jason, i am aware of how to do that with native iOS but i need it for Xamarin forms. Can you kindly explain why did you assume that i didn't search for that already

Comment: Use DependencyService to access platform specific behavior from XF